# Function Template Overloading - Specialization

Tags: c++

According to *The C++ Programming Language, Special Edition, **Bjarne Stroustrup***, section 13.3.2:

```
template<class T> T sqrt(T);
template<class T> complex<T> sqrt(complex<T>);

void f(complex<double> z)
{
    sqrt(z);      // sqrt<double>(complex<double)
}
```

He states, that although both templates are valid candidates, the second one, `sqrt<double>(complex<double>)` will be preferred over the first one, because it is the most specialized template.

My esteemed compiler, `gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)` seems to disagree:

```
ft.cpp: In function ‘void f(std::complex<double>)’:
ft.cpp:28:11: error: call of overloaded ‘sqrt(std::complex<double>&)’ is ambiguous
     sqrt(z);
           ^
ft.cpp:28:11: note: candidates are:
ft.cpp:9:21: note: T sqrt(T) [with T = std::complex<double>]
 template<class T> T sqrt(T);
                     ^
ft.cpp:10:30: note: std::complex<_Tp> sqrt(std::complex<_Tp>) [with T = double]
 template<class T> complex<T> sqrt(complex<T>);
                          ^
```

Am I doing something wrong (although I copied the code character for character)? Or is it an implementation error for my compiler?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That works, although I don't know why. Please elaborate. Why does it not work without brackets around `sqrt`?

Comment: because [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) finds [std::sqrt(const std::complex<T>&)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sqrt)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thank you. From the compiler output I concluded that the clash was between two candidates `T sqrt(T)` and `complex<T> sqrt(complex<T>`, when in fact the ambiguity was between the standard `complex<T> sqrt(complex<T>&)` and `complex<T> sqrt(complex<T>)`. Please add as answer. Error was, as it usually turns out to be, on this side of the monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete error message reveals one more candidate:

> /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/complex:894:5: note: candidate: std::complex<_Tp> std::sqrt(const std::complex<_Tp>&) [with _Tp = double]

i.e., the one that lives in the `std` namespace, namely the [`std::sqrt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sqrt) overload for `std::complex`. Since you're using an unqualified name, the lookup rules are extended to search the function in the namespaces of function call arguments ([ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)). The solutions are as follows:

#### Option #1

Change the name of your `sqrt` function so that it does not collide with any from the standard library.

#### Option #2

Use a qualified name when referring to your function:

```
::sqrt(z);
```

#### Option #3

Disable ADL by means of using parenthesis:

```
(sqrt)(z);
```